# fstream constructor causing access violation

Tags: c++, file-io, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble reading from a file. I've cut my program down and down until all I'm left with is not much more than Hello World - and I'm still getting an error of 'access violation'.

The error is occuring on the line fstream f(..); - it never gets as far as f.good(). The ***only*** changes to this project have been to include ozz-animation header files and .lib's (easily found on Google), as well as setting Runtime Library mode to /MT rather than /MD. Ozz was throwing the same error when attempting to read a file (hence the cutting down until I'm left with what you see). The file is present, although I don't believe it should matter. Code is as follows:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  fstream f("C:\\Users\\thoma_000\\Desktop\\Limitless\\Bin\\Asset\\skin_example\\A.txt");
  if (f.good())
  {
    OutputDebugString(L"\n\n\nGOOD.\n\n\n");
  }
  else
  {
    OutputDebugString(L"\n\n\nBAD.\n\n\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Please* post the entire error message *verbatim*, including location info. And are you saying this *exact* code *without* linking the Ozz libs nor including their headers *still* exhibits this issue?

Comment: I know this isn't related to your issue, but `#pragma once` in a source file is rather unnecessary.

Comment: You are saying the line `fstream f...` throws an error? So, if you comment out that (and the `if` and `else`) it's ok? What's the actual error?

Comment: Full Error is - "Unhandled exception at 0xDB91B7C2 in LimTestbed.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0xDB91B7C2."

Comment: Entire source is shown above- without linking to Ozz I still get the same error. 

Not sure what you want me to uncomment because if I uncomment it, then the main function will just be "return 0;" ..?

Comment: @TomBurbeck _"0xC0000005: Access violation "_ That usually indicates an uninitialized or NULL pointer being dereferenced.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - The ENTIRE source is shown above, I haven't missed something out in posting this - there are no pointers.

Comment: @TomBurbeck Stack trace?

Comment: `The only changes to this project have been to include ozz-animation header files and .lib's`  Those changes are not trivial, as header files (assuming Visual C++) can contain #pragmas that can turn on/off various options that can affect compiling and linkage.

Comment: Stack trace is giving "The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded." - And I've tried removing the lib's and headers as per a suggestiona above and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: "Frame not in module" is also displayed when attempting to access the error location, I'm assuming something inside the windows/fstream dll's.

Comment: It was probably not a good idea to change `/MD` to `/MT`. One links with DLL runtime lib, the other with static runtime lib. You don't want different parts of your app using different runtime libs.

Comment: It's all compiled against MT. I swapped because Ozz is compiled against MT- and Ozz is giving the same error. If everything is compiled against the MT setting then there's no reason it wouldn't work- correct?

Comment: @TomBurbeck - At this point, maybe it would be better to create a brand new project, and set the runtime library to `/MT`.  Do not add, change, or do anything else.  Compile/link your program.  Does it run?  If not, then you have a broken Visual Studio.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Brand new project (Empty project). Included the two DLL's, attempt to read a file. Works in MDd but not MTd. Thats with no other project changes, and no other source code. Broken Visual Studio? What should I do? Is there a repair option?

Comment: @TomBurbeck - `Included the two DLL's`? You can't add DLL's to a project, as DLL's are not used in the build process.  They only come into play when your program runs.  I stated to not make *any* changes except to change the setting to `MTd`.  If you can't get the simple C++ program that uses streams to run, then you have a broken build environment.  How to fix?  That may mean a reinstalll or a repair of Visual Studio.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry I meant headers not DLL's - Windows.h and fstream. Thats all I've done. Attempting a repair now.

Comment: @TomBurbeck - Do you have multiple versions of VS installed?  If so, did you make sure you placed these versions in separate folders?  The only thing I can think of is that your DLL runtime being used is the wrong version.

Comment: Seriously, just try the `return 0;` thing

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie only have 2013 installed on this machine.

Comment: Could not reproduce with VS2012. Try using wfstream and changing order of includes - Windows/VS sometime does weird things with char types joggling and unicode/non-unicode runime linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by creating the project initially as an empty win32 project rather than a Windows project. I have been through the project settings and I currently can't tell what setting is causing the problem - but at least I have a resolution.